# Get the most accurate user location in [insert timespan]?

Tags: android, gps, location

I am currently able to get the location when I set the `Criteria` accuracy to `ACCURACY_COARSE`. This uses the mobile signal to get the location I believe and returns it straight away.

What I wish to do is the the most accurate location I can within (for example) 1 minute before I store/do whatever I need to with the location.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Should I get the location first with `ACCURACY_COARSE` and then try for `ACCURACY_FINE`? Will it work? Ie. if I remove the update request after the 1 minute is up will it actually stop requesting, or can I only remove it after the first report?

Is the a better way of approaching this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to request updates from both providers (you can use the same listener though). There is an example at [Android's developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) on how to choose the best location update over time.